# Add a new column in dataframe with common value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df1 as:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple | Apple |
| orange | 0 | orange |
| Cake | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | Banana | 0 |
| 0 | grape | grape |

Logic: To add the common value to a new column. If value (other than zero) is present in one or two columns then compare them and add the common value.

I want to add a new column (New_col) to this dataframe with values like below:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | New_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple | Apple | Apple |
| orange | 0 | orange | orange |
| Cake | 0 | 0 | Cake |
| 0 | Banana | 0 | Banana |
| 0 | grape | grape | grape |

Any suggestion how to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df1['New_col'] = df1['col1']`?

Comment: Thank you. i have now edited the table, This solution will not work.

Comment: That's why you should explain the logic, not just dump two tables for us to guess ;) I bet I can find a logical solution that is not what you want

Comment: Yeah! I am sorry. Realised after your first comment.

Comment: And so, what is the logic? ;)

Comment: I didn't get it neither

Comment: Maybe pick up the value that is not a zero in each row?

Comment: Yes but which one? First? Last? Max? Random?

Comment: Sorry again for my bad writing. I have eidted now and hope this makes it clear

Comment: So you always have zero or identical values? Then I guess my solution should work for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming**, you want to get the **first** non zero value per row, you can `mask` the zeros and `bfill` then get the first column:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.mask(df.eq('0')).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

*NB. I am also assuming 0 is a string. You can now adapt this code to your needs*

Output:

```
     col1    col2    col3  NewCol
0   Apple   Apple   Apple   Apple
1  orange       0  orange  orange
2    Cake       0       0    Cake
3       0  Banana       0  Banana
```

Comment: Thanks Mozway! This worked like a booom!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @mozway 's solution: Get the index of the first occurrence different from '0' with `.ne("0")` and `.idxmax` for each row using `.apply`, and assign the result to the new column.

```
>>> df["new_col"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.ne("0").idxmax()], axis=1)
>>> df

     col1    col2    col3  newCol
0   Apple   Apple   Apple   Apple
1  Orange       0  Orange  Orange
2    Cake       0       0    Cake
3       0  Banana       0  Banana
```

Comment: Thank you Joao! its good know other alternative solutions as well!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for the ***key with maximum occurrence in any row*** and use it as the item in the new *AggregateCol*

on that note - I would first create a **Numpy** array of the same length as the number of elements in the dataframe, *len(df)*

```
>>> a = {'col1':['AA','BB','CC',0], 'col2':['AA',0,0,'DD'], 'col3':['AA','BB',0,0]}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)

>>> print(df)

col1 col2 col3
0   AA   AA   AA
1   BB    0   BB
2   CC    0    0
3    0   DD    0

>>> a = np.array(len(df) * [0], dtype='object')

>>> print(a)

[0 0 0 0]
```

Next have a function which -
(a) creates a dictionary object with the count of each item that is seen in the rows,
(b) fills up the numpy array with the maximum occurrence of an item

We can make a small modification here if you dont want to count the 0's

```
>>> def f1():
    idx = 0
    for row in df.iterrows():

        # dictionary object to store occurrences of each item in the row
        # you could also use a collections.Counter to achieve this
        d = {}
        for item in row[1]:
            if item in d.keys():
                d[item] += 1
            else:
                d[item] = 1

        # find the item with max occurrence
        max_key = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[0]
        #print(f"{idx=} {max_key=} {d=}")

        # fill the numpy array index with the max_key
        a[idx] = max_key
        idx += 1   

>>> print(a) 

['AA' 'BB' 0 0]
```

The next part becomes easy with you just needing to assign the populated numpy array elements into the new column

```
>>> df['AggregateCol'] = a

>>> print(df)

col1 col2 col3 AggregateCol
0   AA   AA   AA           AA
1   BB    0   BB           BB
2   CC    0    0            0
3    0   DD    0            0
```